# Letting users change array values by dragging a plot line in java

Tags: java, user-interface, input

I have a bit of a tricky question. I have an ArrayList with double values in it. I would like the users to be able to change these values easily.

Ideally I want to display the array as a line plot and allow users to drag the line. When they click ok, the new line is accepted and saved as an arraylist again.

I have worked with java quite a bit, but I don't know how I can make a draggable line plot and use that as input. Any suggestions are highly valued!

It doesn't even necessarily need to be java. Could be something web based that I could call from java...

Comment: Would a JSlider be an option?

Comment: I think that wouldn't account for the time dimension. There would be about a 1000 entries in the array. So I am thinking more of an adjustable curve.